# Picking balls from a bag where we know at least one ball is red

Tags: probability

There are $N$ balls in a bag, of which some number $R$ are red. The probability of picking a red ball from the bag is:

$$p = R / N$$

We are told that at least one ball is red ($R \geq 1$). How does this affect the probability of picking a red ball from the bag?

You could write this as

$$ P(p | R \neq 0) $$

then Bayes allows us to write

$$ P(p | R \neq 0) = \frac{P(R \neq 0 | p) P(p) }{P(R \neq 0)} $$

I've tried writing some of these parameters using the binomial theorem but ended up in a bit of a mess.

Comment: So we don't know from the beginning how many balls are red?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Also, is the number of red balls supposed to be random?

Comment: @Arthur nope, nor the number of balls in the bag

Comment: Then what _do_ we know? If we don't know _anything_, then we can't speak of probability.

Comment: @Frpzzd added attempt

Comment: $\frac{1}{N} \le p \le 1$ ?

Comment: @trueblueanil that seems reasonable. I guess you can't infer any more information about the possible values of $p$ without more information?